# Is it possible to get a count of HTML elements in an Angular ng-show expression?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a select element that has several option elements that are conditionally added.  I would like to do a check and not show the select element at all if there are no option elements within it.  Is this possible from within an Angular expression?

```
<select id="actionsDropDown{{request.id}}" class="reqActions"
        ng-show="(Need to check number of options)"
        ng-model="listing.requestAction[request.id]">
    <option value="EDIT_REQUEST" ng-if="isRequestEditingEnabled(request, listing)">Edit Request</option>
    <option value="RESEND" ng-if="isRequestResendEnabled(request)">Resend</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, there's nothing in the model to bind the check to.  Each ng-if is a mutually exclusive test.

Comment: It depends. Could you provide a fiddle or snippet for us to see how you are implementing it?

Comment: could you not just use the two checks you are using for the options? though, i'd move those out of functions if at all possible.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on your implementation but I assume you have a collection in your controller which you are binding to your select:

`$scope.collection = [1, 2, 3..];`

So you could do the following:

```
<select ng-model="model" ng-show="collection.length">
    <option ng-repeat="item in collection" ng-value="item" ng-bind="item"></option>
</select>
```

What the ng-show directive is doing is hiding the select control when collection.length is falsy. If the collection array has any elements then it will be truthy the it will be shown.